# Grid filtering pass result to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On the page [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MoonStorm/pkuca2f8/) I have a grid.

In `$scope.myItems` I have my data.

I want observe the data. After I type in the name field "Enos", I want to get only records which contain that string ("Enos").

The grid works, but I want to print the data using console log, because after filtering data I want to pass the data to another function.

I tried use `$scope.watch` but it's not working.

```
      .module('myApp', ['trNgGrid'])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.myItems = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                 {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                 {name: "Enos", age: 99}];

        $scope.$watch('myItems', function(newValue) {
       console.log(newValue);   });
        }]);
```

When I type sth to field console log isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer can be found from documentation http://moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid/release/#/GlobalOptions

```
<table tr-ng-grid items="myItems" filtered-items="myFilteredItems"></table>

$scope.myFilteredItems = [];
$scope.$watchCollection('myFilteredItems', function(items){
  console.log(angular.toJson(items));
});
```